# Double group by SQL for day of week and hour/minute

Tags: mysql, sql

Every minute I have a value in my database. Each record has a timestamp, and a value. 

`"30695","2015-09-06 18:10:09","693"`

I want to get the average value for each minute for each day of the week, but I'm not sure how to build a query for this.

My thinking is that I first need to group all the records by `DATEPART(weekday,[time])`, which will put all my data into Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc. Next, I would group by minute, rounded. (So 2015/11/30 06:41:**28** would get grouped with  2015/11/23 06:41:**56** (both dates are Mondays)). Then, take the average of the value at each minute--7*24*60 = 10,080 total values.

Answer (score 1):

There is no datepart() function in mysql, but you can use [dayofweek()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to get the day of the week and [minute()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) to get the minute part:

```
select dayofweek(timestamp) as day, minute(timestamp) as minute, avg(value_field) as average
from table
group by dayofweek(timestamp), minute(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, adapted from Shadow's answer, which wasn't quite right. Here's my query (MySQL 5.5)

`` SELECT weekday(timestamp) as day_of_week, avg(avg) as average, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%H:%i') as hour_time
FROM audio
GOUP BY hour_time, day_of_week
ORDER BY `day_of_week` ASC ``